# Btrfs: Remove a large file takes long

Tags: synology, btrfs

I'm running a synology nas DS1817+ with DSM 6.2.2-24922 with a RAID5 volume formatted with BTRFS.

Deleting a large file either with DSM FileStation or directly in an ssh session with "rm filename" takes a long time.

```
bash-4.3# ls -al
total 31362720
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root         154 Apr 13 05:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root          86 Apr 13 05:09 ..
-rw------- 1 root root 42949672960 Apr 13 05:09 Zoll-VM-flat.vmdk

bash-4.3# time rm Zoll-VM-flat.vmdk 

real    7m24.817s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m6.435s
```

Why? Looking at iotop it seems to be, that it reads and writes the whole file?!?

Comment: I believe this to be an issue with BTRFS itsef, (See: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID56).

Comment: The linux 5.6 kernel has a mount option `discard=async` [1].  I'm keenly curious if that will affect this use case.

[1] https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kdave/linux.git/commit/?h=for-next&id=717b684118e3c3c73e4beeea8535b3bb90c33ebb

Comment: I have a RAID1 system and see 13 seconds to `rm` a 48GB file.

Comment: @Klaus Is it possible you are using shingled magnet recording (SMR) disks?  See this benchmark...  

https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/06/western-digitals-smr-disks-arent-great-but-theyre-not-garbage/

Answer (score 1):

`btrfs` is a CoW filesystem which uses 4K blocks as the base "record" size. This, for large files with intense rewrite workload (*as your vm disk file*) will cause immense **data and metadata** fragmentation. You can check data fragmentation by running `filefrag -v <diskfile>` and counting the number or fragments; when altering each fragment, a metadata record should be create/modified.

With volumes on classical mechanical disks, deleting such files will require a fair amount of time, especially when running on raid5/6.

So I don't think you can avoid that long delete time. Give a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/764635/is-this-btrfs-snapshot-removal-performance-normal) for a similar case.

Comment: I should mention that this is only a backup system, so the file was only written once and i doubt that there will be much fragmentation. Sadly there is no `filefrag` tool on the Synology NAS